# How redirect a tomcat server to another tomcat server?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

My workspace is, a machine with 2 tomcats installed in diferent ports (ex.: 8080 and 8085).
I want to know if I can redirect to 8085 if 8080 is down or busy?
My webapplication is only local.

Comment: If your Tomcat is down, tis probably too late for it to do anything. You need to place some load-balancer in "front" of Tomcat. You could use Apache, pointing to two (clustered) Tomcat instances.